# Spring 3 @ImportResource with multiple files

Tags: java, spring, spring-3

I'm trying to find the syntax for importing multiple spring xml context files using Spring 3 @ImportResource annotation.

I have tried using comma to separate the filenames as illustrated below but that does not work:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("spring-context1.xml", "spring-context2.xml")
public class ConfigClass { }
```

The doc for @ImportResource says "Indicates one **or more** resources containing bean definitions to import." so I believe there should be a way to specify multiple context files. Surprisingly, I've not been able to find any example on Google

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Try:

```
@Configuration  
@ImportResource( { "spring-context1.xml", "spring-context2.xml" } )  
public class ConfigClass { }
```

Comment: ahh needed curly braces. Thanks ajames

Comment: In case you want to import a resource that is outside the classpath the syntax would be `@ImportResource( { "file:path/spring-context1.xml", "file:path/spring-context2.xml" } ) ` Just adding this because it seems like it could be helpful for people who come accross this post.

Answer (score 11):

You need to add the classpath before the file name

```
@ImportResource(value = { 
    "classpath:file1.xml",
    "classpath:file2.xml"
    })
```

Comment: Same answer as 2 years ago. Please delete.

Comment: @WaleryStrauch What? Seriously? Not a reason for anything. This answer looks perfectly fine.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Yes seriously! There is no reason to copy relevant part of answer given 2 years ago and paste as a new answer again. Vote for delete.

Comment: @WaleryStrauch Then down vote and forget about it. No point in flagging it as low quality, which is how I found this. Let it go.

Comment: @Zizouz212 In my opinion this should not be downvoted and forgotten - this should be deleted. This is the reason why I flag it. Still vote for delete.

Comment: You have to add classpath to make it work , your answer was missing that.

Comment: Upvoted because there is no other answer that includes "classpath:" prefix needed to work.

Comment: BTW, `classpath:` prefix is described at https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/reference/resources.html

Answer (score 4):

Just adding for future reference if anyone is using this in a **groovy** project.

In groovy the correct syntax uses **[ ] square brackets** . The curly braces will lead to compilation errors. Please find the example below.

```
@Configuration  
@ImportResource( [ "spring-context1.xml", "spring-context2.xml" ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct format to define multiple spring resources spring xml context files using Spring 3 `@ImportResource`:

```
@Configuration  
@ImportResource( { "spring-context1.xml", "spring-context2.xml" } )
```