# How to load multiple configuration file from classpath using @ImportResource annotation in Spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I don't know,how to load multiple configuration files from classpath in spring using @ImportResource.I have already gone through the link  [Spring 3 @ImportResource with multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004674/spring-3-importresource-with-multiple-files) but no luck so far. My code is below.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:apis.application.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.surfnet.oaaas.resource", "org.surfnet.oaaas.service"})
@ImportResource({"classpath:spring-repositories.xml,classpath:commonApplicationContext.xml"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SpringConfiguration {

}
```

Exception i am facing is

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring-repositories.xml,classpath:commonApplicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
```

How ever when i try to load a single file,like below.it works for both file.But i can not include two `ImportResource` annotation in a java class.

```
    @ImportResource("classpath:spring-repositories.xml"})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the wrong syntax. Look carefully at how it's done in the question you linked to.

There are two strings, not one string containing names separated by commas:

```
@ImportResource({"classpath:spring-repositories.xml", "classpath:commonApplicationContext.xml"})
```

Answer (score 3):

But you were almoust right:) It is simmilar like ComponentScan:

```
@ImportResource({"classpath:spring-repositories.xml","classpath:commonApplicationContext.xml"})
```

When you define resources inside {}, than you put each resource as separate String, optionally with file:, classpath: prefix.

I have found also this stack page:

[Spring 3 @ImportResource with multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004674/spring-3-importresource-with-multiple-files)