# Spring import in java based configuration

Tags: java, spring, configuration

Perhaps I phrased the question wrong. I meant to say that I want to load all java configuration file available in the class path instead of the applicationContext.xml. Something like this -

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("Some other configuration java files which might be in the dependant projects but in the same classpath")  
public class AppConfig {

}
```

Comment: `@ImportResource`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004674/spring-3-importresource-with-multiple-files

Answer (score 1):

Try with `@ImportResource` annotation to import your xml configuration in java based configuration

```
@Configuration  
@ImportResource("classpath*:beancontext/applicationContext.xml")  
public class AppConfig {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Perhaps I phrased the question wrong