# Unable to load Ignite config spring bean definition from non default location in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, ignite

I am trying to externalize my ignite configuration in my spring boot application so the configuration can be changed without rebuilding the jar.

Previously the file resided in src/main/resrouces and was loaded via annotations.

```
@ImportResource("IgniteConfig.xml") and 

@Autowired 
private IgniteConfiguration cfg;
```

When I moved the IgniteConfig.xml to the config folder that resides next to the excutable jar the above stopped working and I have tried the following without success:

1. use --spring.config.location argument.  I can tell this is picked up during run time as other configurations work but the above ImportResource annotation says the file  IgniteConfig.xml cannot be found.
2. use a relative path to (e.g. ./config.IgniteConfig.xml) to Ignition.start.  I cause this relative path to print the file contents of the xml file in my logs but when I pass it to Ignition.start it says the file cannot be found. I have tried using relative and absolute paths to do this.
3. Manually create an ApplicationContext and get the configuration by bean name.

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("./config/IgniteConfig.xml");
```

This again complains that the file does not exist even though I can see by opening the file directly:

```
File igniteConfigFile = new File("./config/IgniteConfig.xml");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by konqi in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004674/spring-3-importresource-with-multiple-files) post answered my question:

"In case you want to import a resource that is outside the classpath the syntax would be:

```
@ImportResource( { "file:path/spring-context1.xml", "file:path/spring-context2.xml" } )
```

"

In my case I just needed to do:

```
@ImportResource( { "file:./config/IgniteConfig.xml" } )
```